# Why does importing 'comb' from scipy fail when using numpy 1.13.3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, google-colaboratory

I am working on feature selection and classification problems in Google Collab. I was able to execute the program with numpy version 1.11.3. Unfortunately, today I encountered an error using numpy(1.13.3) as scipy no longer supports 1.11.3 in Collab. I was working with numpy 1.11.3 because it just worked for me though it may be old. It seems 'comb' can be no longer imported in the python environment. How can I make this work with newer versions of numpy? Also, how and where do I check for such incompatibility issues for other libraries that may arise in the future?

I tried manually typing 'from scipy.misc import comb' and 'from scipy import comb' but it still doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_classif
from time import time

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore');
selector=SelectPercentile(f_classif , percentile = 8)
t0 = time()
X_newDoS = selector.fit_transform(X_DoS,Y_DoS)
print ('Time =', time() - t0)
```

The error message I got was: "ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'"

Comment: Can you try install scipy1.3? It should automatically update numpy as it is a dependency. And Numpy 1.16 if it does not update by itself

Comment: The code you show does not seem to import `comb`, please either show your import, or the full traceback.

Comment: @Eskapp It works on newer versions of numpy. Just wanted to know why it didnt work at the time of posting this question when it was working fine a week ago. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ev-br I think collab no longer supports installing numpy version below 1.13.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the doc of scipy,

```
from scipy.misc import comb
```

has been deprecated since version 1.0.0. Should use

```
from scipy.special import comb
```

instead.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html